# Strange CSS bug with re-rendering an element in React upon Redux store change

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, rendering

I've run into a small bug whose origins I don't understand.

I have some rows whose data lives in a Redux store and which are iterated over and rendered. These rows can be selected and deleted, which updates Redux and causes the rows to re-render correctly.

However, there's a slight CSS bug (shown below): upon the row's deletion, some of the checkboxes' border-bottom attribute (or rather, the div containing the checkbox element) isn't being displayed correctly. The row selection checkboxes are a child of the individually rendered collection, and each parent element in the collection has a key equal to the row's unique ID. But for some reason, just the checkbox-containing element isn't re-rendering correctly.

[image: Screencapture]

In the image, I delete a row, and the borders are wonky for some of the checkboxes. I inspect the element, and un-check and immediately re-check the border-bottom attribute for these elements, and it's back.

Now, I've found a workaround for this. In the React component, I initialize state with a timestamp, and upon row-deletion update this timestamp with the current time. Then, for the elements containing the checkbox, I add a key equal to `rowId-currentTimestamp`. This forces these elements to re-render immediately upon deletion of a row, and this resolves the issue.

However, I still have no idea why this is happening, and am perplexed. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: check your code to make sure you do not mutate the state directly, i.e. `const state={a:123} state.b=456  setState(state)` is wrong. `const state={a,123}; setState({...state,b:456}) `

Comment: There's very minimal use of local state in this component: most meaningful changes are happening through Redux updates, and our Redux store is filled with immutable.js objects.